# Java Possible Lossy Conversion Double to Int

Tags: java

So this is my program which is linked to a driver program. I am having the problem possible lossy conversion and I understand where I am having it but I do not know how to fix it. I need to re-arrange a `Double[] array = new Double[20]` by ordering the numbers from lowest to highest as shown below. How can I do this correctly with out making significant changes to my program?

```
public void insert (double val){
  if(count < 20){
    if(val >= 1 || val <= 10){
      array[count] = val;
      count++;
    }
  }                                  
}

double min;
double max;
double tmp;

for(min = count - 1; min > 0; min--){
   max = 0;
   for(int i = 1; i <= min; i++){       // Error here because of the min value
      if(val[i] > val[max]){          // Error here because of the max value
         max = i;
      }
   }
   if(max != min){
      tmp = val[max];                  // Error here because of the max value
      val[max] = val[min];            // Error here because of the min value
      val[min] = tmp;                  // Error here because of the min value
   }
}
```

Comment: Your loop doesn't appear to be in a method, also where is `list` (or is it `array`) defined?

Comment: It looks like he already has it defined, he just wants to sort it, but i see your point xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `min` and `max` variables shouldn't be doubles. They are array indexes, so they are bounded in practice by 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Change them to `int`.